# Un-excluding specific folder

Tags: git

I want `/vendor/*` to be ignored except `/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/`.

Based on this question: [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

I came up with following `gitignore`

```
/vendor/*
!/vendor/magento/
/vendor/magento/*
!/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/
```

When I do `git status` it is only tracking `/vendor/magento/` but nothing inside it.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Try `git status -uall`. (Git doesn't track, or have as untracked, directories; `git status` just *summarizes* by default.)

Comment: Thanks, you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git status` command allow 3 modes, the default one does not show files within non tracked directories.

From [git-status doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#git-status--ultmodegt):

> **-u[<mode>]**
>
> **--untracked-files[=<mode>]**
>
> Show untracked files.
>
> The mode parameter is used to specify the handling of untracked files. It is optional: it defaults to all, and if specified, it must
>   be stuck to the option (e.g. -uno, but not -u no).
>
> The possible options are:
>
> **no** - Show no untracked files.
>
> **normal** - Shows untracked files and directories.
>
> **all** - Also shows individual files in untracked directories.

---

By default `git status` is in `normal` mode.

You can use `git status --untracked-files=all` or `git status -uall`.